# On Mac, Rcpp does not have lib folder

Tags: c++, r, macos, rcpp, rinside

On Mac OS X 10.7.5, I installed Rcpp and RInside on R 3.0.2. If I go to RInside folder, I can see both lib and libs folder. However, in Rcpp folder, there is only libs folder that contains Rcpp.so and Rcpp.so.dSYM directory. Should Rcpp contain a lib folder with something like libRcpp.a and libRcpp.dylib so that I can link to it in g++?

Thank you!

Comment: From `?LdFlags`, the package no longer builds or ships a user library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment by @josilber is entirely correct.  With the 0.11.0 release, we no longer need a user-facing library for Rcpp.  As its NEWS file said:

```
  \item Functions provided/used by \cpkg{Rcpp} are now registered
  with R and instantiated by client package alleviating the new for
  explicit linking against \code{libRcpp} which is therefore no
  longer created.
```

RInside, as well as many other packages, was updated accordingly.  From the ChangeLog of RInside:

```
* inst/examples/*/Makefile: Note that Rcpp (>= 0.11.0) no longer
requires the RCPPLIBS variable

    [...]

* src/Makefile: PKG_LIBS no longer points to Rcpp's library
* inst/examples/standard/Makefile: Note that Rcpp (>= 0.11.0) no
longer requires the RCPPLIBS variable
```